Encountering Error When Interacting with Smart Contract Using Foundry
When running "make mint ARGS="--network sepolia"", I encountered the following error:
make mint ARGS="--network sepolia"

[⠆] Compiling...

No files changed, compilation skipped
Traces:
  [1131599] → new DevOpsTools@0x4DB574C3D6D412a9eF15B4DDA4442a59ce4877cc
    └─ ← 5710 bytes of code
  [228575] → new MintBasicNft@0x5b73C5498c1E3b4dbA84de0F1833c4a029d90519
    └─ ← 1080 bytes of code
  [6857] MintBasicNft::run()
    ├─ [3925] DevOpsTools::get_most_recent_deployment("BasicNft", 11155111 [1.115e7]) [delegatecall]
    │   ├─ [0] VM::readDir("./broadcast", 3) [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← the path broadcast is not allowed to be accessed for read operations
    │   └─ ← the path broadcast is not allowed to be accessed for read operations
    └─ ← the path broadcast is not allowed to be accessed for read operations
Error: 
script failed: the path broadcast is not allowed to be accessed for read operations
make: *** [Makefile:45: mint] Error 1

Script contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {DevOpsTools} from "lib/foundry-devops/src/DevOpsTools.sol";
import {BasicNft} from "../src/BasicNft.sol";

contract MintBasicNft is Script {
    string public constant PUG = "ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json";
    function run() external {
        address mostRecentlyDeployed = DevOpsTools.get_most_recent_deployment("BasicNft", block.chainid);
        mintNftOnContract(mostRecentlyDeployed);
    }

    function mintNftOnContract(address contractAddress) public {
        vm.startBroadcast();
        BasicNft(contractAddress).mint(PUG);
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}

I'm aiming to mint an NFT through my smart contract using an Interactions file with Foundry.

add this to your toml file
fs_permissions = [
    { access = "read", path = "./broadcast" },
    { access = "read", path = "./reports" },
]

